# String from response object cannot be converted to string

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert a json response object into a string but I have an issue 
This is the documentation I am using to convert to a c# nuget package

https://craftyclicks.co.uk/docs/postcode-lookup/#full-address-rapidaddress

More specifically this bit to do with returning any errors.

> https://craftyclicks.co.uk/docs/postcode-lookup/#debugging

```
  public void GetRapidAddressByPostCode(string mPostCode)
    {

        mApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CraftyClicksApiKey"];
        string urlToApi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CraftyClicksApiUrl"];


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(urlToApi))
        {
             url = String.Format(urlToApi + "?postcode={0}&response=data_formatted&key={1}",
              mPostCode, mApiKey);

        }
        else
        {
             url = String.Format("http://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/json/rapidaddress?postcode={0}&response=data_formatted&key={1}",
          mPostCode, mApiKey);
        }



        //Complete XML HTTP Request
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        //Complete XML HTTP Response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        //Declare and set a stream reader to read the returned XML
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Get the requests json object and convert it to in memory dynamic
        // Note: that you are able to convert to a specific object if required.
        var jsonResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        // check that there are delivery points
        if (jsonResponseObject !=null || jsonResponseObject.delivery_points !=null)
        {

            //If the node list contains address nodes then move on.
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var node in jsonResponseObject.delivery_points)
            {
                ClsAddress address = new ClsAddress()
                {
                    AddressID = i,
                    AddressLine1 = node.line_1,
                    AddressLine2 = node.line_2,

                    County = jsonResponseObject.postal_county,
                    PostCode = jsonResponseObject.postcode,
                    Town = jsonResponseObject.town



                };

                addressList.Add(address);
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {




    foreach (var node in jsonResponseObject)
            {
                // Get the details of the error message and return it the user.
                switch ((string)node.Value)
                {
                    case "0001":
                        mStatus = "Post Code not found";
                        break;
                    case "0002":
                        mStatus = "Invalid Post Code format";
                        break;
                    case "7001":
                        mStatus = "Demo limit exceeded";
                        break;
                    case "8001":
                        mStatus = "Invalid or no access token";
                        break;
                    case "8003":
                        mStatus = "Account credit allowance exceeded";
                        break;
                    case "8004":
                        mStatus = "Access denied due to access rules";
                        break;
                    case "8005":
                        mStatus = "Access denied, account suspended";
                        break;
                    case "9001":
                        mStatus = "Internal server error";
                        break;
                    default:
                        mStatus = (string)node.Value;
                        break;
                }
            }




        }
    }
```

But the problem I am getting is it says it cannot convert array to string at the switch statement. I think the problem is when i accessing delivery points when it does not exist i think my null check

**Edit to show valid json**

When  A post code is not found the following json will be returned

> {"error_code":"0001","error_msg":"No data was found for the requested
>   postcode."}

However when a valid property post code is found it will return the following.

> {"delivery_points":[{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"1
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488593","dps":"1A"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"3
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488604","dps":"1B"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"5
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488606","dps":"1D"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"7
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488608","dps":"1E"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"9
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488610","dps":"1F"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"11
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488595","dps":"1G"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"15
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488598","dps":"1H"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"17
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488600","dps":"1J"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"2
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488603","dps":"1L"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"4
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488605","dps":"1N"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"6
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488607","dps":"1P"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"8
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488609","dps":"1Q"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"10
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488594","dps":"1R"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"12
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488596","dps":"1S"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"14
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488597","dps":"1T"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"16
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488599","dps":"1U"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"18
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488601","dps":"1W"},{"organisation_name":"","department_name":"","line_1":"19
>   HUNTINGDALE
>   CRESCENT","line_2":"","udprn":"03488602","dps":"1X"}],"delivery_point_count":18,"postal_county":"COUNTY
>   ANTRIM","traditional_county":"COUNTY
>   ANTRIM","town":"BALLYCLARE","postcode":"BT39 9YY"}
>
> System.ArgumentException: 'Can not convert Array to String.'

the json in question is as follows

Showing My Debugging at present.

[image]

Comment: Posting a valid json may help you to get better answers

Comment: @L.B that is valid json as how it not in my comments

Comment: :))) copy your json from question and paste to  http://json2csharp.com/ or https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @L.B please see update I have corrected my json sorry for that

Comment: @david I don't think that this code is what you are really using. Since the check " if (jsonResponseObject !=null || jsonResponseObject.delivery_points !=null)" will never return false in your case, and based on the json object retrieved this will return true and will not go to the code that throw this exception.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas it is the code I am really using just copied it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a problem in your code that is caused by the following check:

```
if (jsonResponseObject !=null || jsonResponseObject.delivery_points !=null)
```

Since this check will return true whether the JSON response returns error object or the expected object that contains delivery_points.

Your code should be like the following:

```
if (jsonResponseObject !=null)
{ 
     if(jsonResponseObject.delivery_points !=null)
     { 
            //If the node list contains address nodes then move on.
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var node in jsonResponseObject.delivery_points)
            {
                ClsAddress address = new ClsAddress()
                {
                    AddressID = i,
                    AddressLine1 = node.line_1,
                    AddressLine2 = node.line_2,

                    County = jsonResponseObject.postal_county,
                    PostCode = jsonResponseObject.postcode,
                    Town = jsonResponseObject.town
                };

                addressList.Add(address);
                i++;
            }
      }
      else
      { 
            foreach (var node in jsonResponseObject)
            {
                // Get the details of the error message and return it the user.
                switch ((string)node.Value)
                {
                    case "0001":
                        mStatus = "Post Code not found";
                        break;
                    case "0002":
                        mStatus = "Invalid Post Code format";
                        break;
                    case "7001":
                        mStatus = "Demo limit exceeded";
                        break;
                    case "8001":
                        mStatus = "Invalid or no access token";
                        break;
                    case "8003":
                        mStatus = "Account credit allowance exceeded";
                        break;
                    case "8004":
                        mStatus = "Access denied due to access rules";
                        break;
                    case "8005":
                        mStatus = "Access denied, account suspended";
                        break;
                    case "9001":
                        mStatus = "Internal server error";
                        break;
                    default:
                        mStatus = (string)node.Value;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That seems to be it but cause i am filling the status as as string is that the correct way to do it is there not better way of throwing the error back